When to use RMS error of sampled distribution vs. error on fit to distribution
I'm fairly new to stats, so maybe this is a bad question, but here goes:
I have a sampled set of numbers from a distribution. I've calculated the mean and RMS of the sampled distribution. I have also done a fit to this distribution to determine the mean and RMS. For a large number of samples, these come out roughly the same, as expected.
I have a second sampling which was taken at another time, and due to potential time dependence of the data, may come from a distribution which has a different mean than the first sampling (i.e., may come from a different truth distribution).
My question, then, is whether I should use the error on the mean from the fit or the RMS of each sampled distribution to determine if the two distributions are different in a statistically significant way.
As an extension, what if the distribution is Lorentzian (a Cauchy distribution) and the variance is undefined (but the MAD is)?
